# Display single blank lines in collapsed sections if they are followed by a higher-level heading

Tags: org-mode

I format my Org mode files with a blank line before and after headings, and two blank lines before top-level headings:

```
* Bands

** 60s

*** Beatles

- John
- Paul
- George
- Ringo

*** Cream

- Eric
- Jack
- Ginger
  
** 70s

*** Iron Maiden


* FooBeer
```

Due to folding single lines of whitespace with the heading, when partially folded the headings abut the higher-level heading following them but not the higher-level heading preceding them. See the `Beatles` and `Cream` headings abutting the `70s` heading but not the `60s` heading:

```
* Bands

** 60s

*** Beatles...
*** Cream...  
** 70s

*** Iron Maiden...

* FooBeer
```

Is there a way to prevent collapsing of blank lines preceding a higher-level heading? That is, display single blank lines in collapsed sections if they are followed by a higher-level heading.

My goal, as applied to this example, is to display a blank line above `70s` when the `Cream` heading is collapsed. Like this:

```
* Bands

** 60s
*** Beatles...
*** Cream...  

** 70s
*** Iron Maiden...

* FooBeer
```

And upon further collapsing:

```
* Bands

** 60s...
** 70s...

* FooBeer
```

Comment: Maybe the variable `org-cycle-separator-lines` can help?

Comment: @NickD Thank you, but `org-cycle-separator-lines` affects all empty lines, setting it to `1` makes the document far too sparse to glance over quickly. If there were a way to set `org-cycle-separator-lines` only when it precedes a heading more primary than the previous heading (such as `70s` or `Foobeer` in the example) then that would help.

Comment: I don't know of any such context dependence (but that does not mean that it does not exist). I was hoping that you'd be able to find a fixed value that would do (at least approximately) what you wanted, but apparently it's not possible.